# AWS API gateway logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is there is a way to access the execution time per each request made to an AWS API gateway?

I need single values, not aggregate metrics (= those visible in CloudWatch Metric Dashboard).

Answer (score 2):

If you enable Cloudwatch logs you'll be able to see each request including timing data per request:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You will only get aggregated values based on api resource or api method if you enable cloudwatch watch logs for API gateway explicitly, by default it will be off. You can even access this data using APIs 
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#id51

**Just a thought :**
Now question is why you need to monitor each and every request individually. Normally you only need to see on an average how things are performing. And that is being taken care by metrics.
API Gateway is just the interface to connect to some other service. For example, if you are connecting to Lambda, you can log in detail, may be even return the execution time in the response. So basically log to some system like loggly or elastic search and access via API calls. Or simply calculate and return the required dimension/parameter in the apigateway response.